# Make an img fullscreen when clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to make an image full screen when clicked on. Similar to hitting f11 in most modern browsers. I've tried screenfull.js but it is really buggy and not cross browser supported that well.

**My HTML**

```
 <div id="photoFrame">
   <img src="uploads/picture01.jpg" class="img" alt="PictureOne" />
   <img src="uploads/picture02.jpg" class="img" alt="PictureTwo" />
   <img src="uploads/picture03.jpg" class="img" alt="PictureThree" />
   ... and so on ...
  </div>
```

**My CSS**

```
#photoFrame {                                                       
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    display: block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    clear:left;
    background-color:#333;
    padding-top:40px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}

#photoFrame img {
    width:auto;
    max-width:80%;
    height:50vh;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

**Side Notes**

The `img` class on the elements can be used by any Javascript.

Any help would be great or even a point in the right direction.

Comment: Like a full screen youtube video?

Comment: document.getElementById(id).requestFullScreen(), but you probably want a polyfill as well.

Comment: @Idris, yes i guess so. When the image is clicked on, the image is increased in size and nothing else but the image is in view.

Comment: You do understand that the image quality will vary? Since you could be stretching a `100x100` to `1920x1080`.

Comment: Yes, when i said full screen, I realise I didn't actually mean fullscreen in that sense, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like...

```
$(".img").click(function(){
    $(this).height($(window).height());
    $(this).width($(window).width());
});
```

**edit**
For an f11 style full screen plugin you should check out https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin. Then edit my above code to...

```
$(".img").click(function(){
    $(this).fullScreen(true);
});
```

Comment: gave this one a try and it just increases the size of the image. I was hoping for a more of an "f11" effect. Probably should have mentioned that in my op. Thank you though.

Comment: Thanks you your edit, yes that was more along the lines of what i am aiming for. I'm not sure why though but after i exit full screen mode, my layout seems to be broken. Specifically the img that was clicked on not being in the same place?

Comment: Can you throw together a sample fiddle to demonstrate the problem? I'd need to see what's happening to get an idea how to fix it

Comment: My guess is when you close full screen or use `$(this).fullScreen(false)` it is also removing the `img` class on top of disabling full screen. If that's the case just add the `img` class again after closing full screen. But that might not be the problem at all

Comment: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/HSCu3/) as asked for but it wont work at all in jsfiddle, maybe because the lib isn't listed, i've tried to add it manually but it still doesnt work. I have a copy of my website on my remote server which has the error on if you wish to view it on there? [My Remote Testing Server](http://www.cundytech.com/BassClef/index.html )

Comment: how would i add the img class again?

Comment: After looking at your server site that doesn't seem to be the problem, although it looks like the link you posted is still using screenfull

Comment: Yes i have been looking at the source code after and it looks like the html remains intact. Yes you are correct i posted the wrong link, it should have been affixed with .php  like this one! [My Remote Testing Server](http://cundytech.com/BassClef/index.php It still reacts the same way though unfortunately.

Comment: As much as i hate admitting defeat this Full-Screen plug in seem like it is made of the same components as screenfull.js. And just like the latter it is terrible across browsers. Just tried it in the big three and all three reacted differently!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a plugin like **lytebox** which is very simple to use and would give you a good result of what you want to achieve:

http://lytebox.com/

Just download the js from the above site and include that into your page

**How to use:**

http://lytebox.com/howTo.php

Its pretty simple and exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, maybe i'm just picky but this plugin looks really dated and pretty ugly.